# Where I can store data for spreading them online?

Tags: server, cdn, datastore, qt-installer

My company have an application which could be installed with Qt Online-Installers. The data are stored on the our personal server, but, with time, we found out, that the internet connection is a bit slow for users on the other edge of the world. So, there is a question - "What services are we able to use to store these data, which are designed for these purposes?". When I was investigating this question I found the Information about the thing which is called "Content Delivery Network", but I'm not sure if it's something fits or not.

Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience in this area, so, maybe somebody knows more and could give me an advice. Thank you!

Comment: This is really vague, and probably off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudfront on AWS . Depends on what your content is but can probably store it on s3 and then use Cloudfront to cache it at edge locations across the globe.

Answer (score 0):

Your research led you to the right topic because it sounds like you could benefit from a CDN. CDNs store cached versions of your website, download files, video, etc. on their servers which is often a distributed network of servers across the globe, known as 'Points of Presence' (PoPs). When a user requests a file from your website, assuming it is leveraging a CDN, the user request actually goes to the closest POP and retrieves the file. This improves performance because the user may be very far from your origin server, or your origin server may not have enough resources to answer every request by itself.

The amount of time a CDN caches objects from your site depends on configurable settings. You can inform the CDN on how to cache objects using HTTP cache headers. Here is an intro video from Akamai, the largest CDN, with some helpful explanation of HTTP caching headers.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAxSE1M4yKE

Cheers.